# Hyperref package. Is there any way to include multiple url addresses in one word (or in any given set of words)?

Tags: hyperref, urls

For example, you can write the following if you want the word ''LINK'' to be clickable and you want to be redirected to Wikipedia every time you click on ''LINK'':

\href{http://www.wikipedia.org/}{LINK}

But, is it possible to assign several urls to the word ''LINK'' above so that when you click on ''LINK'' several web pages get opened?